# How to find the name of the user with whom the file is shared?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a file, user and share models like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    time_overview = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size_overview = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    flag_r = models.TextField()

class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()
```

I found out the number of users with whom the particular file is shared using this query:

```
shared_file = File.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id).values_list('files', flat=True)).annotate(count=Count('share__shared_user_id'))
```

Now, I want to find out the users name with whom the particular file is shared.
Tried using this:

```
shared_username = User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True))
```

Didn't get it right. I want to get the username with whole the particular files are shared. How can I do this?

Comment: what is shared_user_id? why isn't it a foreign key? why is it there when you already have a foreign key to user?

Comment: log_id is the user who is currently logged in. log_id = request.user.id and shared_user_id is the user with whom the file is shared.

Comment: users is who shared the file and shared_user_id is with whom the file is shared.

Comment: ok got it i'm writing an answer will post it in a few mins

Comment: and users in File is the owner of file? which may be different from the person who shares it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition of a particular file name in the second queries:

`shared_username = User.objects.filter(id__in = Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id, files__file_name='file1').values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True))`

---

However your model has some problems worth noting:

1- If you replace `Share.shared_user_id` with a OnetoMany field your model would be more correct and your queries a lot easier.

2- If you use `related_name` on your foreign keys you can access them from the opposite model and your queries would be much easier.

3- You should not use plural var names for foreign keys as they represent one object. `File.users` should be `File.user` and the same for `Share.files` and `Share.users`

4- Your model could be a lot more readable if you name your vars properly. For example instead of `File.users` you could use `File.owner` or `File.owning_user`. Same with `Share.users`: `Share.sharing_user`.

Comment: I looped over it and found out the username for it gives me the username for all the files. For example: file ok.txt can be shared with user 'hello' and file 'e.txt' can be shared with user 'fds' and 'sdf'. This query gives me all the user names for every files but I don't want that. I want to find the username to a particular file only.

Comment: See updated answer: add `files__file_name = 'asd.txt'` to your filter.

Comment: All the files are populated in a row from shared_file query. There will be a shared_no for each file when the user clicks on that only the shared_username for particular file has to be shown.

Comment: In one sentence can you write the query you want?

Comment: 'list of users that file1 has been shared with them' is `shared_username = User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(files__file_name = 'file1').values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True))`

Comment: Dude what's file1? I don't want to give the static file name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26351/discussion-between-jurgenreza-and-user2032220)

Comment: I have done like this:
 shared_file = File.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id).values_list('files', flat=True)).annotate(count=Count('share__shared_user_id')) 
        file1 = [i.file_name for i in shared_file]
        shared_username = User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id, files__file_name=file1).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True))
It's not working though. User name is empty.

Comment: Yeah but I have problem to show it in template. I have posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474953/how-to-print-list-according-to-index-in-django-template?noredirect=1#comment21907755_15474953

Comment: If you can please answer that question too. Thanks